# Confused on calculating the result

Tags: javascript, json

I've a json as below.

```
const words = [{
    "Id": "1",
    "Status": "Not Started"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Status": "Not Started"
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    "Status": "Completed"
  },
  {
    "Id": "4",
    "Status": "Not Started"
  },
  {
    "Id": "5",
    "Status": "Not Started"
  }];
```

Using Javascript, I want to calculate the `Completed` Percentage, here in current json, it should be 20%, since there are 5 items and 1 is complete.

Here is the code that I wrote.

```
const users = [
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "Status__c": "Not Started"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Status__c": "Not Started"
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    "Status__c": "Completed"
  },
  {
    "Id": "4",
    "Status__c": "Not Started"
  },
  {
    "Id": "5",
    "Status__c": "Not Started"
  }
];

let nS = users.filter(it => it.Status__c==='Not Started');
let cm = users.filter(it => it.Status__c!=='Not Started');

console.log(nS.length +' \t' +cm.length);
```

This is giving the exact result of the count. But here I want the percentage. Also there may be 3 or 7 in the result(doesn't have 5 all the times), I want this percentage to show the result in those cases even.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered this? 
`cm.length / users.length * 100 + '%'`

Comment: @OrkunTuzel It should be `cm.length / users.length` and not `cm.length / nS.length`.

Comment: indeed, missed it and fixing in my comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just count the completed items using `reduce` and then divide it by the total number of items:

```
let completedCount = users.reduce((count, it) => count + (it.Status__c === "Completed" ? 1 : 0), 0);

let completedPercentage = 100 * completedCount / users.length;
```

**Note:** You may want to check if `users.length !== 0` before dividing.

Comment: Does reduce method has any advantage over filter method?
`let completedCount = users.filter(it => it.Status__c ==='Completed').length`

Comment: @OrkunTuzel `reduce` is better in this case because you only want the count. `filter`  creates a new array that contains the filtered items which you don't use at all excepts to get the count which seems like a waste. Each Array method has its proper use, counting is what `reduce` is for not `filter`

Comment: Javascript is never about performance optimisations (like not creating arrays) but more about readability of the code. From this standpoint, `filter` is a more idiomatic approach, as what you do is literally filtering completed items and counting them. With reduce implementation it's less clear what's going on, for example, what are those 1 and 0 for? How do they map to "completed" status? Why is there both filtering and summing going on at the same time? What should I need to change if I want to add one more check on top of "completed"? (...)

Comment: ... It takes time to stop and understand what's going on, I'd personally stick with `filter`

Answer (score 2):

Filter by status, and then do the percentage math.

```js
const users = [{ "Id": "1", "Status__c": "Not Started" }, { "Id": "2", "Status__c": "Not Started" }, { "Id": "3", "Status__c": "Completed" }, { "Id": "4", "Status__c": "Not Started" }, { "Id": "5", "Status__c": "Not Started" }];

const percentComplete = (data) => 
    (data.filter(({Status__c: s}) => 
        s === 'Completed').length / data.length) * 100

const result = percentComplete(users)
console.log(`${result.toFixed()}%`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the basic simplified loop.

```js
const words = [{
    "Id": "1",
    "Status": "Not Started"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Status": "Not Started"
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    "Status": "Completed"
  },
  {
    "Id": "4",
    "Status": "Not Started"
  },
  {
    "Id": "5",
    "Status": "Not Started"
  }
];

function calculatePercentageByStatus(status, arr) {
  let total = arr.length;
  let matched = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].Status === status) {
      matched++;
    }
  }

  return (matched / total) * 100;

}

console.log("percentage of Completed " + calculatePercentageByStatus("Completed", words) + "%");

console.log("percentage of Not Started " + calculatePercentageByStatus("Not Started", words) + "%");
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this very simple.

```
console.log(cm.length * 100 / users.length + '%');
```

This should work.

Comment: Why are you asking us if this works? You are providing a solution, you should know if this works or not.